# A phrase to relate these two sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

I wrote:

> Subsequently, some approaches to information extraction used the regions returned by VIPS as the basis for detecting and extracting relevant data. _______ VIPS is considered as a region extractor.

I try to connect these two sentence to each other but I can't come up with a good phrase! Maybe, "in this respect", "in this sense", "in this view", "in this regard" ... are some options. But I've been said that these phrases must have an antecedent and I am not sure what could be that antecedent.

Comment: The phrase "the regions returned by VIPS..." is the antecedent.  "In this regard" works perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge is that, due to the highly technical subject matter, it's not clear what the relationship between the two sentences should be.  Your "subsequently" is given without the previous context, so there isn't enough information to understand the material.

But I can guess.  If you are trying to restate the previous sentence (VIPS is the basis for detecting data, i.e. VIPS is a "region extractor") then there are various possibilities.

> **Therefore**.  Used if you are summing up a logical sequence.
>
> **In other words**.  Used if you are simply rephrasing the previous sentence.
>
> **In this regard / respect / sense**.  Used if you are presenting another aspect of the previous sentence that adds more information that may not be obvious.
>
> **Consequently**.  Used if the sentence is a natural consequence of the previous logical sequence.  Note this "clashes" with "subsequently" -- it's a little odd to use both in the same paragraph or logical sequence, unless as a deliberate way to organize a complicated thought.

Of course, without any understanding of what VIPS is and how it works, "however", "nevertheless", "despite this", and various other transitions work just as well.  There's really no way to know.

Comment: I think John Felts' comment answers the question. VIPS acts as a pre-stage to other information extractors. It detects the regions existing in a web document. Other method use this output to identify relevant and informative regions. ------ VIPS is considered / acts  as a region extractor [in comparison with information extractors].

Comment: @Ahmad Again, without knowing more information, I wouldn't be that certain.  Personally, I think "in this regard" is not the phrase that best fits, but then I would probably rewrite the entire paragraph to enhance clarity, eliminate redundancy, and avoid the need for the transition phrase.